# 2D array how to print a number and it's coordinates

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need to find and print out the max and min number in each row of a 2D array. This is what I have tried so far.

```
int max(int N, int masyvas[][])
{
    int i, j, max[N][N]
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=i; j<N; j++)
            if(masyvas[i][j] > max) max=masyvas[i][j];
    return max;
}
```

I know this doesn't work, but is it any close to being at least useful? Any suggestions on how should I approach this?

Comment: Good morning, Do you want to print the minimum and maximum of each row of the matrix?

Comment: Yes. I also want to print their coordinates accordingly. So for example if my matrix is 5x5, and the maximum number is 9 at row 1 column 5. I would like to printf("The maximum number in row 1, 2, etc.. is 9 and it's coordinate's are 1 and 5") well something of these sorts :)

Comment: Go step by step.

 1. Write a program to find min and max of 1D array. Print them with co-ordinates.
 2. Call this function for every rows of your 2D array.

Comment: MayurK - Can I do it all in the main function? If  I do it in seperate functions and return min/max, it only returns the number not it's coordinates?  I'm sorry if my questions seems silly, I'm a bit new to c language.

Comment: You can use pointers in function arguments to pass multiple values back to calling function. But if you are not aware of pointers, first implement main function to find and print min and max. Then extend it to 2D array.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to manage it somehow. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i, j, max, min;
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
  max = 0;
  min = 0;
  for(j=i; j<N; j++    ) {
    if (masyvas[i][j] > max) 
       max = masyvas[i][j];
    if (masyvas[i][j] < min) 
       min = masyvas[i][j];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're  very close.  The two  main problems  are `max`  type (it  shouldn't be
another array, but  just a normal `int`),  and the fact that  you didn't reset
your `max` value before each row.

```
int i, j, max;
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    max = 0; // reset max before checking a row
    for(j=i; j<N; j++) {
        if (masyvas[i][j] > max) max = masyvas[i][j];
    }
}
```

It shouldn't be difficult to add a `min` check too:

```
int i, j, max, min;
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    max = min = 0; // reset max & min before checking a row
    for(j=i; j<N; j++) {
        if (masyvas[i][j] > max) max = masyvas[i][j];
        if (masyvas[i][j] < min) min = masyvas[i][j];
    }
    // print the values here
}
```

Now, you say you want  to print those values. You can do so  at the end of the
outer loop, as  marked above. Returning the final value  like in your original
code doesn't make much sense since only  the final row max and min would still
be there.  Another approach, which  might be what  you intended though,  is to
make max and min an array and return a pointer:

```
int *maxValues = calloc(sizeof(int) * N);
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    for(j=i; j<N; j++)
        if (masyvas[i][j] > maxValues[i]) maxValues[i] = masyvas[i][j];

return maxValues;
```

You probably already  noticed that to return both max  and min values (arrays)
you will need another level of pointers...

```
int **
find_max_and_min(int **masyvas)
{
    int **values = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2);
    values[0] = calloc(sizeof(int) * N); // to hold min
    values[1] = calloc(sizeof(int) * N); // to hold max

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < N; j++) {
            if (masyvas[i][j] > values[1][i]) values[1][i] = masyvas[i][j];
            if (masyvas[i][j] < values[0][i]) values[0][i] = masyvas[i][j];
        }
    }
    return values;
}

int **result = find_max_and_min(data);
// now result[0] is a 1d array of N size with the minimal values of each
// row i from data, and result[1] is a similar array but holding the max
// of each row.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Now I only need to figure out how pointers work :x

Comment: Of course, this is a very specific code. If you're going to deal with pointers, pointers to pointers, and having them passing from and out of functions you have to guarantee that memory management and overall safety of memory access is done correctly...

Comment: oh, I have another question. What if I didn't need to find every min of every row, but the minimum number of those max and print its coordinates. For instance : I have a 4x4, and the max numbers are 4 3 8 9 from all four rows, so the minimum from that is 3. How do I store/manipulate without pointers, so that it prints 3 and its coordinates?

Comment: @Rytis :D it is a big subject. You can see that it goes far, as it progresses

Comment: @Rytis the logic is similar, just run another loop on the final max array that you found and check for the min

Comment: @Rytis just now I see what you mean by coordinates. Well, you have then to record the i and j, could be using a struct for example.

Comment: could you recheck my comment, I edited it. I'm new to this page, so I keep failing by pressing enter over and over again :x

Comment: But what if I can't do that and my code is restricted only to arrays?

Comment: I see. I'm sorry that I understood your question incorrectly! Please check the answer by @eyllanesc . I think it is much cleaner and what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Output {
   int value;
   int pos;
};

void max(int N, int masyvas[N][N], struct Output max_by_rows[N]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        max_by_rows[i].value = masyvas[i][0];
        max_by_rows[i].pos = 0;
        for(j=i; j<N; j++)
            if(masyvas[i][j] > max_by_rows[i].value)
            {
                max_by_rows[i].value=masyvas[i][j];
                max_by_rows[i].pos = j;
            }
    }
}


void min(int N, int masyvas[N][N], struct Output min_by_rows[N]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        min_by_rows[i].value = masyvas[i][0];
        min_by_rows[i].pos = 0;
        for(j=i; j<N; j++)
            if(masyvas[i][j] < min_by_rows[i].value)
            {
                min_by_rows[i].value=masyvas[i][j];
                min_by_rows[i].pos = j;
            }
    }
}

int main(){
    int N = 4;
    int a[4][4] = {
        {0, 1, 2, 3} ,
        {7, 6, 5, 4} ,
        {8, 9, 10, 11},
        {15, 14, 13,12}
    };
    struct Output maxs[4];
    struct Output mins[4];
    max(N, a, maxs);
    min(N, a, mins);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <N; i++)
    {
        printf("row %d \tmax: %d\tpos: %d\tmin: %d\tpos: %d\n", i, maxs[i].value, maxs[i].pos, mins[i].value, mins[i].pos);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
row 0   max: 3  pos: 3  min: 0  pos: 0
row 1   max: 7  pos: 0  min: 4  pos: 3
row 2   max: 11 pos: 3  min: 8  pos: 0
row 3   max: 15 pos: 0  min: 12 pos: 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I wrote the excercise incorrectly, I can't use structures and I have to find the minimum of the maximum numbers. Also my array size is and input by hand it can be any size. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.